# Can a “Dual Rank Memory Module of 8 Gb” added to two " single rang module of 4Gb"?

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I have poweredge T20 is capable of supporting up to 32 GB.

I presently have 2 slots filled with the following memory:

Two of 4GB 1Rx8 PC3L-12800E DDR3-1600MHz Unbuffered Single Rank Memory Module

ANd i want to add RAM with this configuration :

Dell 8 GB Certified Memory Module - 2Rx8 DDR3 UDIMM 1600MHz LV ECC.

I can work normal?

Comment: If it fits in your computer and you are certain that it is capable of supporting up to 32 GB, then why wouldn't it work?

Comment: The manual at http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/poweredge-t20/T20OwnersManual/System-Memory?guid=GUID-D3FE8F79-8D36-4F3E-9A41-8D0F1759A45D&lang=en-us specifies ` Maximum DIMM Rank/Channel`. To me that implies that single and dual rank should work.

Comment: i can't the information.

Comment: Verify your current memory is ECC and verify your motherboard supports ECC memory